# MongoDB Aggregation, Mongodb Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using **Nodejs and MongoDB with expressjs and  mongoose** library, creating a **Blog API** having ***users***, ***articles*** & ***comments*** schema. Below are schemas that I use.

```
const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:        { type: String },
    email:           { type: String },
    date_created:    { type: Date },
    last_modified:   { type: Date }
});    




const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:              { type: String, required: true },
    text:            { type: String, required: true }, 
    posted_by:       { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    images:          [{ type: String }],
    date_created:    { type: Date },
    last_modified:   { type: Date }
});




const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:             { type: String, required: true },
    commented_by:   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    article:        { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article' },
    text:           { type: String, required: true },
    date_created:   { type: Date },
    last_modified:  { type: Date } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) aggregation from mongodb **3.6** and above

```
Article.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "posted_by": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Comment.collection.name,
    "let": { "id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$article", "$$id" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "comments"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "comments_no": { "$size": "$comments" },
    "hasCommented": { "$in": [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id), "$comments.commented_by"] }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Ok then remove the `$match` stage if you want to get the data for all the users. *it is not returning the exact number of comment* It should not happen

Comment: Yes, it is working but when [MongoDB Replicaset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) is enabled. if it is enabled, you will not be able to use some aggregation functionality including `$lookup` so be careful.

Comment: @GorKotikyan The restriction on `$lookup` (as at MongoDB 4.0) is that the `from` collection must be unsharded and in the same database -- you can still use the `$lookup` command in a replica set or sharded environment. For expanded support there is a relevant feature request you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue: [SERVER-29159: Add $lookup support for sharded collections](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29159).

Comment: Hello, @AnthonyWinzlet can you help me on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54376551/9159002