# MongoDB Aggregation Query to Count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using **Nodejs** and **MongoDB** with expressjs and **mongoose** library & How can I get **mutual** between another user. Here are the Schema I use.

```
const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:        { type: String },
    email:           { type: String },
    date_created:    { type: Date },
    last_modified:   { type: Date }
});    


const FollowSchema = new Schema({
    follower:        { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    following:        { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    date_created:    { type: Date },
    last_modified:   { type: Date }
});
```

How do I Query **Mongo**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 2 }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "follows",
    "let": { "id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$facet": {
        "userFollows": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$follower", "$$id"] }}}
        ],
        "myFollows": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$follower", 1] }}}
        ]
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "matchedFollowed": {
          "$setIntersection": ["$userFollows.followed", "$myFollows.followed"]
        }
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$matchedFollowed" }
    ],
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "follows",
    "let": { "ids": "$user.matchedFollowed" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$follower", "$$ids"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "mutualConnections"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Yes that’s the right aggression, but be aware if MongoDB collection is sharded, ՝$lookup՝ functionality won’t work, please refer to [MongoDB Jira task](https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-29159)

Comment: Hello @Anthony Winzlet, How can I query mongo to suggest a specific user to follow other users based on accounts he follow

Comment: @byal Please ask a new question with proper explanation